# Passing an ArrayList of any type to a method

Tags: java, android, generics

I'm working on my first Android app, a math game for my kid, and am learning Java in the process.  I have two `ArrayList`s, one of integers `0..9` and one strings of possible operations, at present, just `+` and `-`.

I would like to write a method that returns a random index into an `ArrayList`, so I can select a random element.  What I'm running into is that I need two methods, one for each type of `ArrayList`, even though the code is identical.  Is there a way to do this in a single method?

What I use now:

```
Random randomGenerator = new Random();

  . . .

n = randomIndexInt(possibleOperands);
int op1 = possibleOperands.get(n);
n = randomIndexInt(possibleOperands);
int op2 = possibleOperands.get(n);
n = randomIndexStr(possibleOperations);
String operation = possibleOperations.get(n);

    . . .

int randomIndexInt(ArrayList<Integer> a){
    int n = randomGenerator.nextInt(a.size());
    return n;
}

int randomIndexStr(ArrayList<String> a){
    int n = randomGenerator.nextInt(a.size());
    return n;
}
```

What I'd like to do is collapse `randomIndexInt` and `randomIndexStr` into a single method.

Comment: You can write a method that will take A (of type `int`) as an argument and return any random number between 0 and A and call this method passing your array list sizes.

Comment: Remember to accept an answer, and maybe +1 if you like someone else as well :)

Comment: +1 for coding a math game for your kid.

Comment: Thanks, all, with the help I got here I was able to improve the method further, and my code now looks like this:

    int op1 = (Integer) getRandomElement(possibleOperands);     
    int op2 = (Integer) getRandomElement(possibleOperands);  
    String operation = (String) getRandomElement(possibleOperations);  
    . . .     
    Object getRandomElement(ArrayList<?> a){  
        int n = randomGenerator.nextInt(a.size());
        return a.get(n);  
    }

Apologies, I can't get this comment to format correctly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

declare your method as  `int randomIndexInt(ArrayList<?> a)`

Comment: It could just be `Collection<?>` since that's what declares `size()`.

Answer (score 7):

You need only the size of the array right?
so do it:

```
int randomIndex(int size){
    int n = randomGenerator.nextInt(size);
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's another approach, and one I'd done earlier, but I actually wanted to push as much common code as possible (including getting the Array size) into the method.

Answer (score 5):

with this code you can pass any type of list

```
int randomIndex(List<?> list){
    int n = randomGenerator.nextInt(list.size());
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Thanks; that worked okay with the array, but the int array chokes it as a primitive type.   I suppose I could use Integer instead of int, but the <?> approach fixed it nicely.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to pass a `List<Integer>` or a `List<String>` into this method.

Comment: Ups, I forget about generics cast. Thanks @PaulBellora.

Answer (score 2):

just make it:

```
private int randomIndex(int size){
return randomGenerator(size);
}
```

And then call them with `randomIndex(yourArray.size());`

Answer (score 2):

More generic is to use `List` than `ArrayList` in method signature.

```
int your_method(List<?> a){
//your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Generics` as follows

declare your function as below

```
private <T> int randomIndex(ArrayList<T> a){
    int n = randomGenerator.nextInt(a.size());
    return n;
}
```

now you can pass `ArrayList<String>` or `ArrayList<Integer>` to this function without any issue like this

```
ArrayList<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
strList.add("on1");
System.out.println(randomIndex(strList));
ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
intList.add(1);
System.out.println(randomIndex(intList));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int randomIndex1(ArrayList<?> a)
{
   int n = randomGenerator.nextInt(a.size());
   return n;
}

int randomIndex2(int size)
{
   int n = randomGenerator.nextInt(size);
   return n;
}
```